# Using SQL database for running tests in Jhipster

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster, spring-boot-test

I have configured the `test` application properties to use Postgresql. All tests seem to work but that is not totally correct.

When I do actual persistent data tests, there is no data being saved to the postgresql db even though liquibase is run.

Relevant section of `application.yml` that I've configured with postgresql.

```
spring:
    application:
        name: stackoverflow
    jackson:
        serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps: false
    cache:
        type: none
    datasource:
            type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
            url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/store_test?user=postgres
    jpa:
        database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL82Dialect
        database: POSTGRESQL
        show-sql: false
        generate-ddl: false
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: none
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
```

As per normal there is a `createEntity` method for say an Entity `Company`

I have tried

```
em.persist(company)
em.flush(company)
```

also

```
companyRepository.saveAndFlush(company)
```

What am I missing to get JHipster to correct test against a real database or if I am saving data incorrectly.

Comment: Show the code that you use to write data and to verify it is or isn't in the database.

Comment: By default, tests generated by JHipster are `@Transactional`annotated so data modification are rollbacked.

Comment: That's what I understand but when I do a  breakpoint at the middle of a test I see the entire table is missing and then it is recreated after the particular unit test is done. When I do a native query it returns no data, but Jpa queries seem to work.

Comment: Does your native query run in same transaction? I doubt it so it can't read your data even when app is stopped at a breakpoint. That's how I understand isolation.

Comment: I didn't understand that statement and how it is applied. Can we talk on gitter?

Comment: I ended using a `.sql` file and using a SQl execution in test
`@Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,scripts = "classpath:importdata.sql")` This is how I was able to test `nativeQuery` and get the objects in database. All other tests do not create the objects in DB (perhaps in-memory?) but they seem to pass.

Comment: I've changed test properties file to use postgres also like you, but still give me errors in liquibase with h2 DB, Did change anything else? @AbhishekDujari

Comment: It's been awhile but this method is applicable only to postgresql and I am running actual sql native queries. You can't use H2 with it unless you change the queries to h2 queries. I dont have access to that code since I left that project over an year ago. However it worked fine in running tests.

Answer (score 0):

as said @gaël-marziou
By default, tests generated by JHipster are `@Transactional` annotated so data modification are rollbacked.
You should `@Commit` annotation for tetMethod to prevent it from `rollback`

Comment: yes, on this he is correct. But even without transactions and calling commit, no actual data is written to DB. Only hibernate will acknowledge it. I am fairly new to Java/Spring and coming from Python/Rails I expected data to be actually written to DB so I can run native queries. That was not the case. Are you saying that my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Yes, whitout @Transactional it should save data, may be there some cases that makes your test transactional(super class, some xml config I am not sure)?!
I did the same, tried `flush,update, save`! My class annotated @Transactional and method annotated @Commit, after this test method leaves data saved in db.